# Are activation records created on stack or heap in C?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

I am reading about memory allocation and activation records. I am having some doubts. Can anyone make the following crystal clear ?

A). My first doubt is that **"Are activation records created on stack or heap in C"** ?

B). These are few lines from an abstract which i am referring :-->

> Even though memory on stack area is created during run time- the
>   amount of memory (activation record size) is determined at compile
>   time. Static and global memory area is compile time determined and
>   this is part of the binary. At run time, we cannot change this. Only
>   memory area freely available for the process to change during runtime
>   is heap.At compile time compiler only reserves the stack space for
>   activation record. This gets used (allocated on actual memory) only
>   during program run. Only DATA segment part of the program like static
>   variables, string literals etc. are allocated during compile time. For
>   heap area, how much memory to be allocated is also determined at run
>   time.

Can anyone please elaborate these lines as i am unable to understand anything ?
I am sure the explaination would be of great need to me.

Comment: I'm curious where that quote is coming from honestly.  It reads rather poorly and I am not at all surprised that it confused you.

Comment: The C standard does not enforce a specific implementation. It does not even require a stack or heap. There is no such thing like "activation record" in the standard. And please refrain from asking for explanation of some text you found somewhere on the internet. Why not ask the author? If you are at it: tell him to use standard terms. _Static_ variables **are** what is often called "global memory". The latter is not used in the standard.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, It has screwed me up. Can you plz make that clearer ?

Comment: Activation records are usually created on the stack. The abstract seems crystal clear to me. I don't know what you know or what you don't know, so it's difficult for me to explain the abstract to you. What do you think the first sentence means?

Comment: @Stuart, is the abstract right ?

Comment: @Stuart: There is absolutely no need for that, nor for a stack.

Comment: first time I hear the term activation record when it comes to c. Also, very poorly worded paragraph being quoted

Comment: @UmNyobe, Yes this paragraph is poorly phrased. Can you rephrase it properly ?

Comment: @Willturner Each C compiler is different, so I can't say that the abstract is correct, in every way, for every compiler. But, the abstract is correct that that is usually how things work.

Comment: whats an activation record?

Comment: @Stuart: The is no need for a stack and most implemenations which do use one don't use it for all local variables/parameters. That depends on the ABI of the respective platform.

Comment: maybe this is useful http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Answer (score 1):

As a quick answer, I don't even really know what an activation record is.  The rest of the quote has very poor English and is quite misleading.

Honestly, the abstract is talking about absolutes when in reality, there really are not at all absolute.  You do define a main stack at compile time, yes (though you can create many stacks at runtime as well).

Yes, when you want to allocate memory, one usually creates a pointer to store that information, but where you place that is completely up to you.  It can be stack, it can be global memory, it can be in the heap from another allocation, or you can just leak memory and not store it anywhere it all if you wish.  Perhaps this is what is meant by an activation record?

Or perhaps, it means that when dynamic memory is created, somewhere in memory, there has to be some sort of information that keeps track of used and unused memory.  For many allocators, this is a list of pointers stored somewhere in the allocated memory, though others store it in a different piece of memory and some could even place that on the stack.  It all depends on the needs of the memory system.

Finally, where dynamic memory is allocated from can vary as well.  It can come from a call to the OS, though in some cases, it can also just be overlayed onto existing global (or even stack) memory - which is not uncommon in embedded programming.

As you can see, this abstract is not even close to what dynamic memory represents.

---

Additional info:

Many are jumping all over me stating that 'C' has no stack in the standard.  Correct.  That said, how many people have truly coded in C without one?  I'll leave that alone for now.

Defined memory, as you call it, is anything declared with the 'static' keyword within a function or any variable declared outside of a function without the 'extern' keyword in front of it.  This is memory that the compiler knows about and can reserve space for without any additional help.

Allocated memory - is not a good term as defined memory can also be considered allocated.  Instead, use the term dynamic memory.  This is memory that you allocate from a heap at run-time.  An example:

```
char *foo;
int my_value;

int main(void)
{
    foo = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    // Do stuff with foo
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

`foo` is "defined" as you say as a pointer. If nothing else were done, it would only reserve that much memory, but when the malloc is reached in main(), it now points to at least 10 bytes of dynamic memory as well.  Once the free is reached, that memory is now made available to the program for other uses.  It's allocated size is 'dynamic'.  Compare that to `my_value` which will always be the size of an `int` and nothing else.

Comment: Static and global variables are known at compile time, right ?

Comment: That is correct.  The main stack is usually defined at compile time as well.

Comment: There is no stack in the C language! It is an implementation detail and not required. I don't see this answers the question ("explain this excerpt"), not that the question can be answered by anyone else than the original author.

Comment: how is the stack defined at compile time? If I recurse based on user input I have a deeper stack depending on what was input. The stack is a dynamic resource (with perhaps OS defined upper limit)

Comment: @Willturner: There are no distinct "global" variables! Just _static_ variables. How about reading the standard instead of obscure resources?

Comment: @Olaf, I am trying to teach here.  Yes, you are 100% correct to the detail that there is indeed no "stack" defined by 'C', but we both know that 99.999999% of programs use one, so let it go.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, Can you please tell the difference between defined and allocated .ie. memory is determined/defined at compile time but allocated at run time .

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: That's actually the point. We are a Q&A, not a tutoring site.

Comment: Ok, he asked a question, I answered it in a way that he will hopefully understand.  If the question were that bad, it would have been down-voted to obscurity and closed in minutes.  It was not.  Someone with 20x my rep came in and answered it with the standard as well.  Hopefully between the 2 of us, good will have been done today.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, a C99 (or C11) compatible implementation (e.g. a C compiler & C standard library implementation) do not even need (in all cases) a [**call stack**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). For example, one could imagine a whole program compiler (notably for freestanding C implementation) which would analyze the entire program and decide that stack frames are unneeded (e.g. each local variable could be allocated statically, or fit in a register). Or one could imagine an implementation allocating the call frames as [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) frames (perhaps after [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) transformation by the compiler) elsewhere (e.g. in some "heap"), using techniques similar to those described in Appel old book [Compiling with Continuations](http://www.cambridge.org/fr/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/compiling-continuations?format=PB&isbn=9780521033114) (describing an SML/NJ compiler).

<sup>(remember that a programming language is a *specification* -not some software-, often written in English, perhaps with additional formalization, in some technical report or standard document. AFAIK, the C99 or C11 standards do not even mention any stack or activation record. But *in practice*, most C implementations are made of a compiler and a standard library implementation.)</sup>

In practice, allocation records are *call frames* (for C, they are synonyms; things are more complex with nested functions) and are allocated on a hardware assisted call stack on all reasonable C implementations I know. on [Z/Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/Architecture) there is no *hardware* stack pointer register, so it is a *convention* (dedicating some register to play the role of the stack pointer).

So **look first at [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) wikipage**. It has a *nice picture* worth many words.

> Are activation records created on stack or heap

In *practice*, they (activation records) are call frames on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (allocated following [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s). Of course the layout, slot usage, and size of a call frame is computed at compile-time by the compiler.

In *practice*, a local variable may correspond to some slot inside the call frame. But sometimes, the compiler would keep it only in a register, or reuse the same slot (which has a fixed offset in the call frame) for various usages, e.g. for several local variables in different blocks, etc.

But most C compilers are [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). They are able to [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) a function, or *sometimes* make a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to it (then the caller's call frame is reused as or overwritten by the callee call frame), so details are more complex.

See also this [How was C ported to architectures that had no hardware stack?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7197) question on retro.

Comment: Can you please tell the difference between defined and allocated .ie. memory is determined/defined at compile time but allocated at run time?

Comment: Congrats, you quoted the standard.  Now, lets teach with something that he might be able to understand...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Where did I quote the standard? I did not even look into it to answer (and no, I don't know it by heart)... And I did take care to give useful hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

In C (given how it is almost universally implemented*) An *activation record* is exactly the same thing as a *stack frame* which is the same thing as a *call frame*. They are always created on the stack.

The stack segment is a memory area the process gets "for free" from the OS when it created. It does not need to `malloc` or `free` it. On x86, a machine register (e.g `RSP`) points to the end of the segment and stack frames/activation records/call frames are "allocated" by decrementing the pointer in that register by how many byte to allocate. E.g:

```
int my_func() {
    int x = 123;
    int y = 234;
    int z = 345;
    ...
    return 1;
}
```

An unoptimizing C compiler could generate assembly code for keeping those three variables in the stack frame like this:

```
my_func:
    ; "allocate" 24 bytes of stack space
    sub  rsp, 24     
    ; Initialize the allocated stack memory
    mov  [rsp], 345      ; z = 345
    mov  [rsp+8], 234    ; y = 234
    mov  [rsp+16], 134   ; x = 123
    ...
    ; "free" the allocated stack space
    add  rsp, 24
    ; return 1
    mov  rax, 1
    ret
```

- In other contexts and languages activation records can be implemented differently. For example using linked lists. But as the language is C and the context is low-level programming I don't think it is useful to discuss that.